# AudioSessionSetProperty in Xamarin / Monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, audiounit

I'm trying to do the following AudioToolbox AudioSessionSetProperty in Xamarin.

```
UInt32 allowBluetoothInput = 1;
error = AudioSessionSetProperty (
    kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput,
    sizeof (allowBluetoothInput),
    &allowBluetoothInput);

if (error) printf("couldn't set Bluetooth Input!");
```

Does anyone know how to do that?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be:

```
AudioSession.OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput = true;
```

Comment: Right on Poupou.  Thank you.